# passing object from one component to another using service file in angular

Tags: angular, service, components, inject, stacked-chart

I am trying to draw a stacked bar chart using Kendo UI and angular. I want to pass data from home component to stacked bar chart component using service file. Home component console shows the dataset correctly but stacked bar chart component does not get the data as input.

**Home component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  homeData: any = [];
  stackedbarchartdata: any = [];
  constructor(private Data: HomeService) {
    this.Data.getMethod().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.homeData = res;
      this.stackedbarchartdata = this.homeData.stackedbarchartdata;
      console.log(this.stackedbarchartdata);
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**home component.html**

```
<kendo-tilelayout-item [col]="3" [colSpan]="2">
  <kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
    <app-stacked-bar-chart [stackedbarchartdata]="stackedbarchartdata"></app-stacked-bar-chart>
  </kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
</kendo-tilelayout-item>
```

**stacked-bar-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stacked-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './stacked-bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stacked-bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class StackedBarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() stackedbarchartdata: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.stackedbarchartdata);
    }
}
```

Json Data

```
"singleBaChartData": {
    "name": "singleBaChartData-TOTAL REVENUE",
    "Title": "TOTAL REVENUE",
    "singleBaChartData": [{ "id": 1,"category": "product1","value": 5},
      { "id": 2,"category": "product2","value": 4}]}
```

Comment: 1. I don't a service b/n the components. And for parent-child relationships using `@Input()` properties, it isn't needed. 2. I don't see anything wrong here (except may be you could make do with an `async` pipe in the template instead of an explicit subscription), so what output do you get for the `console.log` in `StackedBarChartComponent`?

Comment: StackedBarChartComponent console show empty array. but home component console show the object correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Kendo `TileLayout` and based on your comment, I can only assume the change detection of `kendo-tilelayout-item` isn't picking up the changes to `stackedbarchartdata` property. There are multiple options to try

#### 1. Use `async` pipe

You could remove the subscription in the component controller and use [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template instead. This should trigger the subscription right from the template the provide the data to the `@Input()` variable.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  homeData: any = [];
  stackedbarchartdata$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private Data: HomeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stackedbarchartdata$ = this.Data.getMethod().pipe(
      tap((res: any) => this.homeData = res),       // <-- is this needed anymore?
      map((res: any) => res.stackedbarchartdata)
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<kendo-tilelayout-item [col]="3" [colSpan]="2">
  <kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
    <app-stacked-bar-chart [stackedbarchartdata]="stackedbarchartdata$ | async"></app-stacked-bar-chart>
  </kendo-tilelayout-item-body>
</kendo-tilelayout-item>
```

#### 2. Manually trigger change detection

There are [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/6513921) to trigger the change detection manually inside the subscription callback *after* the property `stackedbarchartdata` is assigned the value. Although I find this a little inelegant.

Comment: now it shows the data in console. but i have another problem on creating graph. can you please help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163525/create-stacked-bar-chart-in-angular-using-service-file

Comment: @prarthanawickramasinghe: I'm sorry, like I said I'm not familiar with Kendo UI and looking at the question, I couldn't grasp immediately what the problem might be. May be you could try to 1.) understand what the output of the `groupBy` function is. 2.) perform the `groupBy` operation inside `ngOnInit()` hook instead of the constructor.